# Return DataFrame rows for max date of every month and only if it falls in the last 2 weeks of that month

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date, dataframe

I'm want to **return rows by checking for the maximum date of the month and then rechecking if the date falls in the last 2 weeks of that particular month**. Below is the DataFrame that I'm using:

`finalPrize        date     high         low`

`1777.44     2018-07-31  1801.83     1739.32`
 `1797.17     2018-06-27  1798.44     1776.02`
 `1834.33     2018-05-28  1836.56     1786.00`
 `1823.29     2018-04-03  1841.00     1821.50`
 `1847.75     2018-03-29  1847.77     1818.92`

I have **referred other answers** and found a way to find the max date from the '**date**' column. Here is the code:

`df.index = df['date']`

`print(df.groupby(df.index.month).apply(lambda x: x.index.max()))`

But, this results into:

`date
1  2019-07-31
2  2019-06-27
3  2019-05-28
4  2019-04-03
5  2019-03-29`

Rather, I want to return all the values from the rows where these dates occur **But** that **date should fall in last 2 weeks**. I'm not able to figure out how to do that!

So **expected output** is:

`finalPrize        date     high         low`

`1777.44     2018-07-31  1801.83     1739.32`
 `1797.17     2018-06-27  1798.44     1776.02`
 `1834.33     2018-05-28  1836.56     1786.00`
 `1847.75     2018-03-29  1847.77     1818.92`

Comment: Last week - calendar week or just last 7 days of a month?

Answer (score 1):

```
import calendar

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df['day'] = pd.to_numeric(df.index.day)
df['days_in_month'] = df.apply(lambda row : calendar.monthrange(row.name.year,row.name.month)[1], axis = 1)
df['first_day'] = df.apply(lambda row : calendar.monthrange(row.name.year,row.name.month)[0], axis = 1)
df['days_in_last_week'] = ((df['days_in_month'])%7+df['first_day'])%7
df[df['day'] > (df['days_in_month'] - df['days_in_last_week'])]
```

Hope this works!Do this after you set date to index.

Comment: I tried this approach but it's giving me data for all the days from last week of each month, rather I want only for the max date of that week.

Comment: Also, for some months it's not giving the result.

Comment: I see you edited to last two weeks, my proposed code will not work. Also you need to to what I proposed after grouping for each month like you described with keeping the highest date for each month.

Comment: Yeah, even before editing it. I tried your solution for last one week. But few records were missing from past year. Like I had a data of more than 10 years. So your solution worked only for some and failed for some dates.

Comment: Sorry about that. You will need to give me an example of failed samples and maybe I can have a  look at it.